# Extracting url within href on html site

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following already extracted from web page:

```
 <a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/in">Indiana</a>,
 <a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/ia">Iowa</a>,
 <a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/ks">Kansas</a>,
 <a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/ky">Kentucky</a>,
```

I only want the **href="united-states/il"** part of each extracted. Currently I am trying something like this:

```
for state in soup_state.find('a',href=True):
    print(state['href'])
```

I continually receive the error:

*AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?*

I want this to be ran in a for loop so I could get each state's url extracted, but am currently unable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you got to `soup_state`, but try:

```
for state in soup_state:
     print(state['href'])
```

and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to find these contents.

```
import re

lines = ['<a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/in">Indiana</a>',
         '<a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/ia">Iowa</a>',
         '<a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/ks">Kansas</a>',
         '<a class="Directory-listLink" data-ya-track="todirectory" href="united-states/ky">Kentucky</a>']

for l in lines:
    print(re.search('href="[^"]*"',l).group())
```

This will give the output:

```
href="united-states/in"
href="united-states/ia"
href="united-states/ks"
href="united-states/ky"
```